# Display a multiplication value between two dynamic text fields

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have these variables:

- dynamic text 1 called `ampere`.
- dynamic text 2 called `tesla`,
- and the slider called `ampereSlid`.

I want to show the result from a mathematical operation that happened in dynamic `text 1` on dynamic `text 2` just by using the slider.

Here's my code:

```
stop();
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import fl.controls.TextArea;

ampere.text = "0";
ampereSlider.value = 0; 
tesla.text= "0"

ampereSlider.addEventListener (SliderEvent.CHANGE, changeAmpere);

function changeAmpere (event:SliderEvent):void{
    ampere.text = event.target.value+"A";
}
 
ampereSlider.addEventListener (SliderEvent.CHANGE, changeTesla);

function changeTesla (event:SliderEvent):void{
    var tsl:Number = 1.25664;
    var tslnum = event.target as TextArea;
    tesla.text = event.target.value;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the `SliderEvent` dispatches properly?

Comment: Where is the mathematical operation that happened on `text 1`? Use [edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65574495/edit) to add useful info towards a working answer. Use more than just 1 sentence to explain your **programming** issue. Give us example of some input slider number then explain: What should happen to that number? What is your expected result from the number?